# Real scheduler for wordpress plugins

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to create a wordpress plugin that performs actions on certain minute intervals like X minutes.
Looking into the WP-API there's the method `wp_schedule_event` which can schedule actions hourly, daily or twice a day.
Is there a way to really schedule events in WP where I can define the exact minute the event should run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
wp_schedule_event('YOUR_LINUX_TIMESTAMP', 'daily', 'my_wp_cron_file' );
```

YOUR_LINUX_TIMESTAMP is `time()`;

Or look at full article: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_schedule_event

The only valid values are 'hourly', 'twicedaily', and 'daily'

BUT:

Open `cron.php` and find a code in "wp_includes/" folder and find:

```
function wp_get_schedules() {
    $schedules = array(
        'hourly'     => array( 'interval' => HOUR_IN_SECONDS,      'display' => __( 'Once Hourly' ) ),
        'twicedaily' => array( 'interval' => 12 * HOUR_IN_SECONDS, 'display' => __( 'Twice Daily' ) ),
            // YOU CODE PUT THERE // 
        'daily'      => array( 'interval' => DAY_IN_SECONDS,       'display' => __( 'Once Daily' ) ),
    );
    return array_merge( apply_filters( 'cron_schedules', array() ), $schedules );
}
```

Add:

```
'minutes'     => array( 'interval' => 60,      'display' => __( 'Once Minutes' ) ),
```

or hourly:

```
'hourly'     => array( 'interval' => 3600,      'display' => __( 'Once Hourly' ) ),
```

And change it as simple:

```
wp_schedule_event('YOUR_LINUX_TIMESTAMP', 'hourly', 'my_wp_cron_file' );   // as exmaple hourly cron is called
```

Comment: I cannot use this as I want to schedule events per minute and not daily so I was asking for alternatives

Comment: And now i'm sure that you can do what you want. Be sure when making update on WP are changed code on cron.

Comment: Great, is there a solution to make it more general, I mean so I can put every 2 minutes, every 6 minutes, every 7 minutes and so on without changing the cron.php file each time?

Comment: Look at this for external cron job, it's also contents a plugin: http://activeblogging.com/info/wordpress-cron-plugin/ downloadable.